# Centre two Edit Texts in row

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a table consisting of two columns. I want to programmatic ally add two EditText fields to each column and so them to be centred in the column.

After reading many questions on this - I am yet unable to get them centred in their column. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private void AddNewRow()
{
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.score_grid);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));

    EditText cell1 = CreateNewScoreBox(player1Rows);
    EditText cell2 = CreateNewScoreBox(player2Rows);

    tr.addView(cell1);
    tr.addView(cell2);

    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
private EditText CreateNewScoreBox(List<EditText> rows)
{
    EditText b = new EditText(this);
    b.setText("");
    b.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    b.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    b.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusLostListener);
    b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    rows.add(b);
    return  b;
}
```

In short I want the two edit texts on the left to be under the Player 1 and Player 2 sections  (and ideally each box to be the same size!).

[image]

Comment: Is it fundamental for you to use the `java` code instead of the `xml` file? In my opinion it would be much easier to do in the layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) right after each declaration of `EditText`:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
cell1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

Arguments of `LayoutParams` are, in order:

1. `layout_width` - in this case `0` for better performance, as the weight will be enough to set the EditText width properly
2. `layout_height` - here you could set a specific number in `dp` if you prefer
3. `layout_weight` - note that it must be a `float`